# Youtubeview with RecyclerView loading

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-youtube-api

I have a `recyclerview` which needs to load `youtube` videos one below the other like a list ,below is the code. I have used `youtube api` for this.

The problem with below code is that only the last video gets loaded, the values passed are correct and working. Other videos in the list do not load and there is black screen for them.

```
public class YoutubeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YoutubeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private String developer_key = "My Developer Key";
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> video_id;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public YoutubeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> video_id) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.video_id = video_id;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        YouTubePlayerView youtubeView;
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            youtubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) view.findViewById(R.id.youtubeView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public YoutubeAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_content,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final String video_string = video_id.get(position);
        holder.youtubeView.initialize(developer_key, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                if (!b) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(video_string);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to load video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return video_id.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean the thumbnails of `youtube videos` is not loading ?

Comment: i have only used i youtube view and not the thumbnailview..what happens is that only the last video with a button is visible and can be played..

Comment: is your `Adapter` contains all data have you checked it's `Array List` size ?

Comment: yes it does contain all the data

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue, so i tried to use POJO class to store all the items. Then use getters in recyclerviewOnBindHolder. It worked.

```
  private YouTube youTube;
    private YouTube.Search.List query;
    public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY="YOUR KEY";

    public YoutubeConnector(Context context) {

        youTube= new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {

            }
        }).setApplicationName(context.getString(R.string.app_name)).build();

        try {

            //this is to filter the query
            query= youTube.search().list("id,snippet");
            query.setKey(DEVELOPER_KEY);
            query.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
            query.setType("video");
            query.setMaxResults((long) 50);
            query.setFields("items(id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/description,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public List<VideoItem> queryResult(){

        try {
            // this is youtube built in SearchResponse
            SearchListResponse response= query.execute();

           List<SearchResult> listResult= response.getItems();

            List<VideoItem> videoItem= new ArrayList<>();

            for (SearchResult result:listResult){

                VideoItem item= new VideoItem();

                item.setTITLE(result.getSnippet().getTitle());
                item.setID(result.getId().getVideoId());
                item.setDESCRIPTION(result.getSnippet().getDescription());
                item.setURL(result.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault().getUrl());

                videoItem.add(item);
            }

            return videoItem;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }

    }
```

So what i did was:

1. I create a class that handles the networking part like i showed above.
2. I create a POJO class called VideoItem.
3. I use youtube built in SearchResponse  -> SearchListResponse response= query.execute();

4.Store all the response in a Youtube built in Pojo class 
 List listResult= response.getItems();

5.I loop all the items  from  listResult and stored it in my own POJO class the VideoItem.

6.I store all my VideoItem inside 
List videoItem= new ArrayList<>();